# How to configure dependency injection in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, configuration, angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm a little bit confused about how angularjs application works.

First of all I should say I'm a **newbie angularjs** user but I'm familiar with other DI frameworks in other languages (like symfony in PHP, spring in Java, a bit Unity).

Each of these DI implementations requires class definitions and **DI configuration**.

Configuration usually includes:

- **how** should be class **injected** (automatically by name or type, or manually)
- if container should return a **singleton** instance
- **what factory class** should be used for creating object
- **serviceIds** - each service can be retrieved by serviceId. This serviceId says configuration of creating instance (what services should be injected and what params should be used).
- etc.

And this **configuration I'm missing in angularjs**.

There is an *dumb* **example** how I expect such a configuration should work. I have two services, each does **similar thing** but with **different implementation**.

```
angular.module('notify', [], function($provide) {
    $provide.factory('LogNotifier', function($window) {
        return {
            messageMe: function(message) {
                $window.console.log(message);
            }
        }

    });
    $provide.factory('AlertNotifier', function($window) {
        return {
            messageMe: function(message) {
                $window.alert(message);
            }
        }
    });
});



angular.module('myModule', ['notify'], function($provide) {
  // as notifier dependency I must specify its type.
  // is there any way how I would configure after its definition
  // which notifier implementation should be used?
  $provide.factory('DataLoader', function(AlertNotifier) {
      var loader = {
          loadAllItems: function() {
              AlertNotifier.messageMe('Loading items');
              // let's asume there is ajax call and promise object return
              return [ 
                    {name: 'Item1'},
                    {name: 'Item2'}
                ];
          }
      }
      return loader;
  });
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/5ZDe6/1/

I would like to **switch** between LogNotifier and AlertNotifier **without changing source code** of DataLoader service. Is that possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a week fiddling with angularjs I realized one very important thing. All angularjs examples actually include the DI configuration I looked for. **The configuration is actually a module definition itself**.

All I had to do was to **separate module definition from class definitions**.
Here is solved fiddle of my question - http://jsfiddle.net/5ZDe6/7/

```
/**
* app module configuration
*/
angular.module('app', ['debug'], function($provide) {
    var dataLoaderFactory = function(Notifier) {
        return new my.model.DataLoader(Notifier);
    }
    // if you want to change notifier just change this injection to AlertNotifier
    dataLoaderFactory.$inject = ['LogNotifier'];  
    // Specify factory with service ID DataLoader for class my.model.DataLoader
    $provide.factory('DataLoader', dataLoaderFactory);    
})
.controller('AppCtrl', my.controller.ItemCtrl); // you can even specify AppCtrl implementation (e.g. CachedCtrl)
my.controller.ItemCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','DataLoader']
my.controller.CachedCtrl.$inject = ['$scope']

/**
* debug module configuration
*/
angular.module('debug', [], function($provide) {
    $provide.factory('LogNotifier', function($window) {
       return new my.debug.LogNotifier($window);
    });
    $provide.factory('AlertNotifier', function($window) {
       return new my.debug.AlertNotifier($window); 
    });
});
```

And there are class definitions separated from DI configuration.

```
/**
* Controller class definition
*/
my = window.my || {};
my.controller = my.controller || {};
my.controller.ItemCtrl = function($scope, loader) {
    $scope.items = loader.loadAllItems();
};

my.controller.CachedCtrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        { name: 'Cached ctrl value 1'},
        { name: 'Cached ctrl value 2'}
    ]
}

/**
* Model class definition
*/
my.model = my.model || {};
my.model.DataLoader = function(notifier) {
    this.notifier = notifier;
    this.loadAllItems = function() {
        this.notifier.messageMe('Loading items');
        // let's asume there is ajax call and promise object return
        return [ 
            {name: 'Item1'},
            {name: 'Item2'}
        ];
    };
};

/**
* Some debug classes definition
*/
my.debug = my.debug || {}
my.debug.LogNotifier = function($window) {
    this.$window = $window;
    this.messageMe = function(message) {
        this.$window.console.log(message);
    }
};
my.debug.AlertNotifier = function($window) {
    this.$window = $window;
    this.messageMe = function(message) {
        this.$window.alert(message);
    }
}
```

I suppose that is the cleanest way how to achieve my requirements. Unfortunately if you really want to do this way you have to **write a bit more code**.

Frank

Comment: I wonder how to bring AngularJS's elegant DI to PHP DIs. Currently PHP DIs seem too much like service containers.